# While I am trying to updating a row to my table, I'm getting the following errors:

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from GSLAB;
+--------+--------------+
| empid  | destignation |
+--------+--------------+
| GS101  | Manager      |
| GS102  | ABC          |
| GS-103 | SAS          |
| GS-104 | dsSAS        |
| GS105  | EWSAS        |
| GS106  | EWQAS        |
+--------+--------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update GSLAB set empid= substr(empid,4,15)||substr(empid,1,2)||'-' where empid substr(empid,1,3)<>'-';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'substr(empid,1,3)<>'-'' at line 1
mysql>
```

Comment: Just looks like there is an unnecessary 'empid' after the 'where'?

Comment: use of || (Or) in update seems odd.  || is concat in oracle unless it's in ANSII mode (https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/162161)  the use of `concat()` would be more explicit if you're wanting to combine strings.

Comment: its not Or it is concat Operator

Comment: I hear you but unless it's in ANSII mode, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html  which is why i'd stick with `concat()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use concat function instead of concat operator '||'

mysql> update GSLAB set empid= concat(substr(empid,1,2),'-',substr(empid,4,15)) where substr(empid,1,3)<>'-';

Comment: The error was in the where condition, which you have fixed in this version.